# Visual Studio 2010 - Cannot add assembly references from the GAC

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, gac

I have now gone over to Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2

I have used it for a few days, but now I can no longer add references from the GAC.

[image]

(http://bildr.no/view/549966)

Sorry since this is not directly a development question, but I was not sure where to ask.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Global Assembly Cache.  You may have done something very very bad.

EDIT

I noticed you are using Silverlight:

> C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0

I cannot find the Microsoft.CSharp.dll I can only find Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to use. Where is the C# dll located for Silverlight 4? I wasn’t able to find it on my computer.

taken from: http://alpascual.com/blog/a-few-issues-with-silverlight-4-after-installing-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Thank you! I will see if this solves the problem! Strange that I do not get any debug info from the VS actually

Comment: But the question is whether I really need "CSharp.dll" when the project is a VB project?

Comment: good question, I suppose it depends on if that file was in fact there in the first place.

Comment: Possible, this resolves itself if using C#, but the resolution did not work when using VB. Is there any way to read the error log. Some space must be lagget an explanation of the error.

Comment: eventvwr in the run dialog may be of some value to you.  Look at the system logs

Comment: Strangely, now I've gone over the system log to Windows 7 And there are not any errors there that is relevant.

Comment: well I am all out of ideas.  Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool which is completely free, that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\Microsoft.CSharp.dll

[source](http://www.inveigledsoftware.com/2009/12/silverlight-4-integrating-with-com/)