# Add dll's to VS2010 using Add Reference after custom install

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, installshield

After installing our custom install (created using InstallShield), the user should be able to use the VS Add Reference to find the dll's without manually adding them using Browse.  This works out of the box for all previous versions of Visual Studio (tested with .NET, 2005 & 2008).  However, the dll's are not present in the Add Reference section under VS2010.  I've tried restarting after install and changing the .NET framework filter to every option available (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5 CP, 4, 4 CP)...

Any ideas are welcomed...I'm beating my head against the wall here.

Thanks,
-jp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assembly installed into the GAC not showing up in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987691/assembly-installed-into-the-gac-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that VS2010 is looking at specific .NET framework keys in the registry now (unlike VS2008 and before).  So the user must use the link Chris pointed to in his answer (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149), but instead add to these .NET framework key locations.

For example, I want my assemblies to be present in all versions of the .NET framework filter within VS2010 Add Reference for .NET tab.  So I will add my assembly under the following 2 locations on a Win7 x64 machine:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx

and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx

...if it's 32 bit only, just remove the Wow6432Node key from the path locations above. Hope this helps someone else. 
-jp

Comment: For clarity, you don't actually but Wow6432Node in the registry table.  MSI will put that in for you based on the fact that your MSI is a 32bit MSI.

Comment: Good find, you are right, that article didn't mention VS2010.