# How to install/deploy .NET DLL so it appears in Visual Studio Add References

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, installation

I'm trying to package a set of compiled .NET DLLs. These comprise x86. x64 and AnyCPU builds of the same library (same DLL name, different version numbers & target platforms).

I am using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), however - assuming an installer agnostic environment, how can I make sure my DLLs show up in the Visual Studio Add-References dialog after an end-user installs my MSI?

Targetting VS2010 and VS2012. Any help gratefully received

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assembly installed into the GAC not showing up in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987691/assembly-installed-into-the-gac-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I tried the answer from there but it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987691/assembly-installed-into-the-gac-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that to make an assembly visible to the Reference Manager in VS2012, I need to add this Registry Key

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\MyAsm
Value: <Directory on target PC of .NET4.0 assembly>
```

And for .NET4.5, I need this key

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.5.50709\AssemblyFoldersEx\MyAsm
Value: <Directory on target PC of .NET4.5 assembly>
```

However this results in another problem of both DLLs showing up when using .NET4.5 ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921846/how-to-install-net4-0-net4-5-x86-anycpu-dlls-side-by-side-in-visual-studio))

Comment: To add the registry is easy with Advanced Installer, you can go to Registry page and in the "Data" field for your new values add a "Folder..." references using the corespondent button. Don't forget to tick the "64-bit component" flag for the components associated with the registry values, so they don't get redirected on 64-bit machines to Wow6432Node. Unfortunately I don't know a solution for the problem with both DLLs showing up when using .NET 4.5

Comment: Thanks for that, helped me with the Wow6432Node issue I was also facing :)