# Sharepoint 2013 PowerPoint Conversion Service - Missing ISAPI Assembly

Tags: sharepoint, powerpoint, sharepoint-2013, powerpoint-2013, powerpoint-automation

We are trying to create a SharePoint farm solution using [**PowerPoint Automation Service**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179894%28v=office.15%29.aspx). However, we are unable to find the *Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint.dll* in the Sharepoint 15 ISAPI hive. This assembly is required for [`PresentationRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.powerpoint.conversion.presentationrequest_members.aspx) access [as seen in this example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/11/12/introduction-to-powerpoint-automation-services-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx).

We do see **Word Automation Service** assembly *Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.dll* in the ISAPI path (*Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI*) - just not the PowerPoint assembly.

Does anyone know where to find the **PowerPoint Conversion** assembly (*Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint.dll*) for **SharePoint 2013**? We need to locate it so we can add an Assembly Reference in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the PowerPoint Conversion assembly in the GAC - but for some reason it is not present in the SharePoint 2013 ISAPI directory. It would have been nice if Microsoft included it in the Sharepoint 15 hive or had the [proper registry key so it would appear in the Add Reference dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987697) - but we can easily [extract it from the GAC or copy the GAC path when adding a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3728434) in Visual Studio.

#### *Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint.dll* Location

`\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint.dll`