# Is there a nuget or Microsoft package for common libraries like System, System.Data, Microsoft.CSharp for VS 2013

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am trying to reference assemblies from one common location (c:\Packages), most of the assemblies I use are from Nuget packages and are added in same location. Only the System libraries like System, System.Data and few which I always reference from framework directory, Wonder if there is a way other than copy/paste to have them at single location. I am using VS2013 C# 5.

Comment: You don't reference them from some Framework directory, you reference them from the GAC. These assemblies are always there, if the framework is installed. You don't need a package for them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - you don't reference assemblies from the GAC. The GAC is *purely* used at runtime. During compilation, you access reference assemblies (the main ones are located under C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987691/assembly-installed-into-the-gac-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio) or plenty of others where people put assemblies in the GAC and are then surprised that they *don't* show up in Visual Studio.